# CS Self-Enrichment

Tags: computer-science

I should be doing something CS related every day as an undergraduate CS major but I don't and feel guilty about it, so I was wondering if there were good CS blogs to subscribe to, CS people to follow on twitter, etc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is a good place to get a technology / programming type blog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089653/where-is-a-good-place-to-get-a-technology-programming-type-blog)

Answer (score 0):

Check google tech videos on youtube and also:

http://scpd.stanford.edu/knuth/index.jsp